# Counting grouped data in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have data in clojure which I have grouped by application into following format:

```
(["name1" [{:application "name1", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
           {:application "name1", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}]]
 ["name2" [{:application "name2", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
           {:application "name2", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}]]
 ...  and so on)
```

I need to count the number of events for each application (i.e. the number of maps in each vector) and produce a list of maps in the format:

```
 ({:application "name1", :count 2} {:application "name2", :count2} ... etc )
```

I have the following code to produce a list of application names and a list of the counts for each application name but I am struggling with how to get them back into the format above.

```
 (let[
  application-list (map first group-by-app)
  grouped-data (map second group-by-app)
  count-list (map count grouped-data)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` offers a really succinct, but expressive way to do something with the elements of sequences to build up a new sequence. I'd certainly recommend it here.

```
(def group-by-app '(["name1" [{:application "name1", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
                            {:application "name1", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}]]
                  ["name2" [{:application "name2", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
                            {:application "name2", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}]]))

(for [[application events] group-by-app]
     {:application application, :count (count events)})

; => ({:application "name1", :count 2} {:application "name2", :count 2})
```

For completeness, however, it's worth noting that `map` can map a function over multiple sequences at the same time. So, you could recombine the intermediate data you produced with a function of the application and the count.

```
(let [application-list (map first group-by-app)
      grouped-data (map second group-by-app)
      count-list (map count grouped-data)]
  (map
    (fn [app event-count]
        {:application app :count event-count})
    application-list count-list))
```

Answer (score 1):

`group-by` produces a map, which is a sequence of key value pairs. You can simply map that sequence.

```
user=> (def foo #{{:application "name1", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
  #_=>            {:application "name1", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}
  #_=>            {:application "name2", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
  #_=>            {:application "name2", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}})
#'user/foo
user=> (map #(let [[key tuples] %] [key (count tuples)]) (group-by :application foo))
(["name1" 2] ["name2" 2])
```

You can turn that back into a map if that's what you need.

```
user=> (into {} (map #(let [[key tuples] %] [key (count tuples)]) (group-by :application foo)))
{"name1" 2, "name2" 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(reduce
  (fn [acc [_ maps]]
    (let [c (count maps)]
      (into acc 
        (map #(assoc % :count c) maps))))
  '()
  grouped)
```

grouped is the grouped data you provided.